# Checking if a NSInteger is odd or even

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have been trying to check whether an NSInteger is odd or even. I have found a way to do it using C but it doesn't work with Objective-C. How would I do this?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`NSInteger` is defined as `int` (or `long` on some environments). So checking on oddity is like for plain int:

```
NSInteger num;
if (num % 2)
  // odd
else
  // even
```

Comment: there must be something wrong with your "integer" variable definition. Anyway I like Horace's answer more

Comment: The definition is: `NSInteger *integer;`

Comment: so you need to dereference pointer to access value stored in it: "if (*integer % 2)"

Comment: so it turns out to be a pointer question but not a type question ;-)

Comment: Joshua: Note that `NSInteger *integer;` declares a variable holding *a pointer to* an `NSInteger`. If that's not what you meant, cut out the `*` from the declaration (and, either way, *do not* dereference the value, since it isn't a pointer).

Answer (score 19):

```
NSInteger n = 5;

NSLog(@"%s", n & 1 ? "odd" : "even");
```

or using if

```
if (n & 1) {
  ; // odd
} else {
  ; // even
}
```

with some output:

```
if (n & 1) {
  NSLog(@"odd");
} else {
  NSLog(@"even");
}
```

the pointer example:

```
NSInteger x = 7;
NSInteger *y = &x;

if (*y & 1) {
    NSLog(@"odd");
} else {
    NSLog(@"even");
}
```

Comment: How would i put this in an `if` statement?

Comment: do you mean nothing prints out? an example with printouts added.

Comment: @Horace, it looks like it's because the OP was using `NSInteger*` rather than `NSInteger`. Since the pointer would almost certainly be aligned, it would always be even. See the comments to Vlad's answer. PEBCAK :-)

Answer (score 9):

As far as I'm aware. `NSInteger`, unlike `NSNumber`, is just a typeder to a real integer type along the lines of:

```
typedef long NSInteger;
```

So you should be able to do:

```
NSInteger nsintvar = 77;
if ((nsintvar % 2) == 0) {
    // number is even
} else {
    // number is odd
}
```

---

Here's a complete program, compiled under Cygwin with GNUstep, which illustrates it:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {
    NSInteger num;
    for (num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
        if ((num % 2) == 0) {
            printf ("%d is even\n", num);
        } else {
            printf ("%d is odd\n", num);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
0 is even
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even
11 is odd
12 is even
13 is odd
14 is even
15 is odd
16 is even
17 is odd
18 is even
19 is odd
```

Comment: Are you sure you're declaring the variable as NSInteger? I've only ever seen that problem ("Invalid operands to binary X", where X is a valid C operator) when you declare the variable as NSInteger* (the pointer rather than the actual integer). Try the fully contained program in my edit.

Comment: I think this answer the best. `((nsintvar % 2) == 0)` is more concise; doesn't mix bool and integer types.

Answer (score 3):

Those other answers should work. Maybe it's a problem with your makefile or something. Think outside that piece of code.

If all else fails just declare the integer as an int. You don't have to declare it as NSInteger.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "%" operator. Essentially, it works out the remainder when you divide a number. So:

number % 2

Would be = 0 if number was even, as an even number divided by 2 has no remainders. If it does not = 0, it must be odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", nil];
// NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];
// NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
// NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", nil];
// NSArray *arrayTotal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", nil];

NSArray *arrLeft;
NSArray *arrRight;

NSRange range;
range.location = 0;
range.length = ([arrayTotal count] % 2) ? ([arrayTotal count] / 2) + 1 : ([arrayTotal count] / 2);

arrLeft = [arrayTotal subarrayWithRange:range];

range.location = range.length;
range.length = [arrayTotal count] - range.length;

arrRight = [arrayTotal subarrayWithRange:range];

NSLog(@"Objects: %lu", (unsigned long)[arrLeft count]);
NSLog(@"%@", [arrLeft description]);

NSLog(@"Objects: %lu", (unsigned long)[arrRight count]);
NSLog(@"%@", [arrRight description]);
```

Hope it helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module operator with if-else statements, e.g.:

```
if ( (number %2) == 0 ){

printf("Your number is even");

} else {

printf("Your number is odd");

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. SInce this is a very old question with multiple popular answers, please edit your answer to identify what you feel it contributes that the others do not. Thanks.